# How to use Kannel without a GSM modem?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel

I am very much new to the telephony technology and terminology. 
I would like to configure my own sms server using Kannel. I have read a lot about Kannel but still I am not sure whether I will be able to configure my sms server with just http server (http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.0/userguide-1.4.0/userguide.html#AEN2103) as SMSC? 
I read about it but things are very much unclear for me.

My goal is to be able to send an SMS on my customer's behalf. Means from the phone number that my customer has registered in my web app.

I don't need to monitor or receive any message to my web app. It would be enough if I can send and I even don't need a acknowledgement as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can I bypass the operator's clutches if I want to deliver my message to my customer? Like in the internet world, I don't directly depend on any ISP to send an email to another internet user. Is this possible with SMS since it is also a standard protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cellular networks & their interconnects are completely private, and not really analogous to the internet. To access them you are always going to have to go through an operator.

Your options are to use a hardware device with a SIM card like a GSM modem or handset, or use a 3rd party gateway (the simplest by far) - its this option that the kannel documentation you linked to seems to be talking about, although if you end up using a gateway a kannel install may be overkill.

Comment: Using a 3rd party gateways, is it possible to set the sender's phone number as well?

Comment: Some gateways allow that (Its called the OADC Number).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible for you to send an sms without using a mobile operator. You will need any GSM attachment to your kannel. Please use a modem and you can send free sms using a modem.